# Why to cast a list in another list

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a method in Spring Data JPA which returns a type of list.

```
List<ModuleAccessEntity> findByNameNotIgnoreCase(String moduleName);
```

Now on ServicesImplimentation.
This list is transferred to another list.

```
moduleAccessEntity=(List<ModuleAccessEntity>) moduleAccessRepository.findByNameNotIgnoreCase("self");
```

here moduleAccessEntity also is list of type.

```
List<ModuleAccessEntity> moduleAccessEntity ;
```

I don't understand why is there a need of putting list in two more lists when we are already getting a list. Can't we do this in easy way like.

```
moduleAccessEntity= moduleAccessRepository.findByNameNotIgnoreCase("self");
```

Comment: there is no compile time error if i do this. but i don't understand the logic behind earlier implementation.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but usually casting return values is only required, if the returned type is not implicitly clearly the expected type. Is `moduleAccessEntity`really of the exact same type (in that particular scope), or might there be a second variable shadowing the one you expect?
I think the purpose of casting here is only to visualize the return type at that point in the code, so it is easier to read. If you always hide types, at some point, reading the code becomes harder.

Comment: Maybe this is some left-over from pre Java5 code? If `findByNameNotIgnoreCase` returned `List` (without generics) in the past, casting might have been necessary to use it with a generified list. If the code is under source code management, you could try to look at past versions of the code to see how it evolved.

Comment: No you don't have a "method in JPA". That method is "Spring Data JPA", a totally different API!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list doesn´t get transferred, it gets castet to `List<ModuleAccessEntity>`. Maybe some earlier implementation has resturned a list without the type, so you had to cast the list. As long as i can see, you don´t need that cast, so change your code as follows:

```
moduleAccessEntity = moduleAccessRepository.findByNameNotIgnoreCase("self");
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a redundant cast, and can be removed. Some IDEs flag this to you as unnecessary.